PSE Advent Calendar 2024 (Day 8): Look, Santa’s Baffled
This puzzle is part of the Puzzling Stack Exchange Advent Calendar 2024. The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth 100 reputation.< Previous Door Next Door >
Look, Santa's Baffled...
... so can you help him?
The Clauses were leaving North Pole Lutheran Church’s Christmas Eve service when the organist called them over. She gave them a brown hymnal with a sheet of paper sticking out.

Cryptic Family Household*

Dumb dictator’s champion shredded cavalier father. (6 5, 4 5)
Turn back after a popular boss exiled a sister. (4 2 1 6)
Mother is regularly in a snug cell, a safer room. At the eerie walls, most of fog also grays. (6 4 3 6 2 5)
Brother took deep sleep. He, instead of old boys, screwed with television sound, which lost 50’s tango. (5 9 6 5)

Translated into emojis**

Let➕☹️ (3 3 8 6 7)
the️’s❄️ (3 4 3 6’1 4)
,♥️➕️⬆️ (4, 4 6 3 6 7)
On✝️ (2 9 5 3 10 4)

Anagrams

Cool fey flu hate-mail (1 4, 3 2 8)
Oh, understand eleven goals (3 3 8 4 2 3)
Mandatory earth wedging (1 5 3 6 6)
Master wets foot (4 4 2 4)


“There’s a final answer, which should come naturally after all that,” she said, smiling. “It’s what you're going to deliver tonight.”
What is the final phrase?

All clues/relevant information are above that ^ line. Below is some meta housekeeping.
Once you figure out the number-sequence, or answers' theme, it’s possible to back-solve the individual clues, since the letter counts are given. Please still explain how each one works. Also, please do not post a partial answer unless you’ve solved at least half the clues.
The number-sequence requires knowledge (definitely not common knowledge, though it is quite Google-able), but there wasn’t space left among the tags.
* A Cryptic Family Household is a Cryptic Family Reunion (cryptic clues where “father” etc. is the definition), except there are only four.
** If the emojis don't show up for you, this is what they're supposed to be:

Thank you @Prince North Læraðr for feedback & developing clue 3!

The answers:

 1 363 Silent night, holy night
 2 365 Away in a manger
 3 367 Angels from the realms of glory
 4 369 Where shepherds lately knelt

 5 371 Let our gladness banish sadness
 6 373 See amid the winter's snow
 7 375 Come, your hearts and voices raising
 8 377 On Christmas night all Christians sing

 9 379 O come, all ye faithful
10 381 Let our gladness have no end
11 383 A great and mighty wonder
12 385 From east to west

The numbers

 are hymn numbers in the Lutheran Service Book.

Explanations for the cryptics:

 1: dumb -> SILENT; dictator's = homophone indicator; knight / holey / knight.
 2: YAW< after A + IN + (MANAGER - A).
 3: alternate letters (yup, the whole thing).
 4: This one's a doozy. "took": WORE. "deep sleep": SOPOR. "He, instead of old": replace each of the three "O"s with "HE", getting WHERESHEPHER. "Boys, screwed": LADS -> DSLA, so now we have WHERESHEPHERDSLA. "with" might go with "screwed" or just indicate appending. "television sound": TELLY KNELL. "which lost 50's": remove two LS, getting TELYKNEL. "tango": T. Put the whole charade together and you have WHERESHEPHER DSLA TELY KNEL T.

Explanations for the emoji:

 5: Let [me] + [you] [happiness] [wave-goodbye] [sadness]
 6: [See] [inbox symbol; but it's got an arrow pointing into the middle of something] the [cold blowing wind]'s [snow]
 7: [Beckoning], [you] [heart] + [voice] [up]
 8: On [Christmas tree] [night sky] [100% of] [cross symbolizing Christianity] [music]

The final answer which should come naturally after all that:

 Continuing to #387 in the same book, we find JOY TO THE WORLD. One might nitpickily suggest that a devout Lutheran would want that joy to come from something more spiritual than getting presents, but I shall be neither a grinch nor a scrooge about this :-).


I'm sorry about clue 4, I swear this version is actually simpler than the original :) "screwed with" is actually a rot13(ebgngvba) indicator. There are four "sections" of wordplay: rot13(yrggre ercynprzrag, ebgngvba, yrggre qryrgvba, naq n svany nooerivngvba). Hopefully that should make it clear... I can also just edit on my explanation if you like

OK, I think I figured it all out.
